# Impact of Apache Log-Files to Serverperformance

Tags: apache, http, logging

Im running a Apache Webserver under Windows Sever 2003.

I noticed that my logfile is bigger then 100MB. If I imagine, that Apache always has to open this file, jump to its end, add a new line and close it again, it seems a good idead to keep this log small.

But is this issue / possible performance-lack really that big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache won't be opening and closing the file all the time - it will keep the file open with the file pointer at the end, ready to write the next line.

So the size of the logfile isn't an issue from a performance point of view.